# Accessing data from a directly unrelated table in dreamfactory

Tags: dreamfactory

I'm using dream factory 2 to create an api for mysql database.
Currently I have several tables but I will use three as an example.
Table 1
   Column A
   Column B
Table 2
   Column A
   Column B
Table 3
   Column A
   Column B

Table 1 can access to table 2 by relational key so Table 1 Col A = Table 2 Column B.
Table 2 can access to table 3 by relational key also so Table 2 Col A = Table 3 Column B.
My question is in Dream factory who would I access Table 3 from Table 1.

Normally if I go into the api docs and and do a request for related data I can pull any related data associated to that table but in this case Table 3 is not directly associated to Table 1.  I know an option is stored procedures but is there away this can be done with Dreamfactory and not using any stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

@Fabricio For queries like this I would recommend using  [virtual foreign keys](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Using_virtual_foreign_keys)

This will allow you to query disparate data not only in different tables but also different databases.

Also,DreamFactory has a [community forum](http://community.dreamfactory.com/) that appears to be quite active. Definitely worth checking out if you have questions in the future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I looked into the virtual foreign keys but as I said in the question Table 1 and Table 3 are unrelated and they don't have a column I can use to relate.  Table 2 is like a "through" so I can connect Table 1 to 2 and Table 3 to 2 but there is no column I can use as a "relational" one between table 1 and table 3.  This is why i was asking the question here.  Do you have any suggestions?